# Making dynamic queries for linked server in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, dynamic-sql, syntax

I want to create a dynamic query in SQL Server which will run on linked server. I am trying to do it as follows.

```
USE [MYDB]
GO

DECLARE @company AS nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @id nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX);

SET @company = 'mycompany.com';
SET @query = N'SELECT @csid = id FROM OPENQUERY(LINKSERVER12, 
   ''SELECT id from company where name = @comp'')';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @company_query, N'@comp nvarchar(50), @csid 
nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT', @comp = @company,@csid = @id OUTPUT
```

In the above script, I want to pass the value for `@comp` dynamically. For that I tried setting input and output variable while executing SQL with `sp_executesql`.

I am getting the following error

> Syntax error in SQL statement. Syntax error line 1 at or after token .[10179].
>
> Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
>   An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT id from company where name = @comp" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKSERVER12".

The error is happening at the dynamic query

```
N'SELECT @csid = id FROM OPENQUERY(LINKSERVER12, 
   ''SELECT id from company where name = @comp'')'
```

I tried replacing `@comp` in the SQL query with '`'@comp''`, `''''@comp''''` with no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

```
DECLARE @company AS nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @id nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT @id = id from company where name = @comp';

exec [LINKSERVER12].[MYDB].sys.sp_executesql @query, N'@comp nvarchar(50), @id nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT', @comp = @company,@id = @id OUTPUT;

select @id;
```